# How query parallelism is implemented in apache ignite?

Tags: bigdata, ignite

I want to know how query parallelism is implemented in apache ignite. The resulting numbers are totally different from the results without parallelism.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without query parallelism Ignite splits query execution between nodes: map request for each node and reduce on node-requester. To perform better on multiprocessor machines, cache indexes are split into smaller parts, just like you're working with nodes_num * queryParallelism.

In that way each node may process same query that was split on query parallelism independent threads.

Comment: I run the same code one time without parallelism and the other with parallelism. the numbers are different as if in case of parallelism records override one another ?!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you want to get the same numbers, what is your goal?